# Adding a new column indicating the row number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have a table in MySQL like:

```
hiredate
2020-02-03
2019-12-03
2018-08-07
```

I want to add a new column right next to it and display the index number:

```
hiredate     no
2020-02-03   1
2019-12-03   2
2018-08-07   3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0:

```
select hire_date, row_number() over(order by hire_date) no
from mytable
order by hire_date
```

In earlier versions, one method uses user variables:

```
set @no := 0;
select hire_date, @no := @no + 1 no
from mytable
order by hire_date;
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do!

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can create a row number column as an Auto Incremental column, which must be a primary key or use the following code:

ALTER TABLE table1

ADD COLUMN rowNumber INT NOT NULL;

SET @row_number = 0;

UPDATE table1

SET rowNumber= (@row_number:=@row_number + 1);

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this code, it looks simple and supported on MySql 5

SELECT
hired_date,
@row_number := (IFNULL(@row_number, 0)+1) AS no
FROM
table_name, (SELECT @row_number := 0) as setrow;